# Importing and Auditing data from SharePoint to an Excel Spreadsheet

Tags: sharepoint, vba, excel

So I bring in data from a Sharepoint Calendar and into an excel spreadsheet.  Is there a way that whenever I import new data from sharepoint it loops through the uniqiue ID that Sharepoint provides and check to see if it has been deleted from the data thats incoming?

So checking against new data coming in against the data currently in the system?

I think what I'll have to do, is upon importing data, store the data in a "Temporary" spreadsheet, then run the loop to comapre the ID's of the Temporary sheet to the Data sheet, then handle the Audit process, then update Temporary to the Data sheet, and lastly delete the temporary sheet.

I need to check ID columns of two worksheets. If an ID is absent i need to pull information from the remaining columns and export that record to another spreadsheet

Never used VBA until yesterday, I was assigned this task, there are no resourceso n google about this. I know what needs to be done. jsut not how to accomplish it.  I need to compare C! in Data to C! in temporary. If there is a cell in Data, thats not in temporary I need to export that entire row to an Audit worksheet.

Anybody know of what commands/macros would be useful for this??

'
Public Sub Find_ID()

```
Dim old_id As Integer, new_id As Integer, oldRow As Variant, newRow As Variant
Dim old_mod As String, new_mod As String

oldRow = 2


Do While Trim(Sheets("Old Data").Range("C" & oldRow)) <> ""
    newRow = 2
    old_id = Trim(Sheets("Old Data").Range("C" & oldRow))


    Do While Trim(Sheets("New Data").Range("c" & newRow)) <> ""
        new_id = Trim(Sheets("New Data").Range("c" & newRow))
        'is new id the same as old id
            'if yes - we have a match, but now we want to compare the modified
                'if modified is a match, then we don't need to do anythying

                'if modified is not a match, we need to figure out what was changed
            'if no - then lets just go to the next line

        newRow = newRow + 1
    Loop


    oldRow = oldRow + 1


Loop'
```

Comment: macros that would be useful for what exactly? Be specific. The more specific and clear you are the easier it will be to answer your question.

Comment: I need to check ID columns of two worksheets. If an ID is absent i need to pull information from the remaining columns and export that record to another spreadsheet.

Comment: Have you attempted yet to create a solution yourself? If you do this, and run into specific difficulties, we can more readily assist you in achieving your ultimate goal here. You may want to see the [ask] FAQ.

Comment: Never used VBA until yesterday, I was assigned this task, there are no resources on google about this. I know what needs to be done. jsut not how to accomplish it.  I need to compare C! in Data to C! in temporary. If there is a cell in Data, thats not in temporary I need to export that entire row to an Audit worksheet.

Answer (score 0):

@floppityflip

you can use the find function if you want to search for something from one worksheet in the other worksheet (since I imagine they will not be in the exact same order) and put that into a loop.

---

Like this:

```
Sub Find()
'
' Find Macro
'

'
    Dim i As Integer
    i = 1
    Dim comparingVariable As String

    Do

        Sheets("Sheet1").Select           'YOUR FIRST SHEET

        Range("A" & i).Select

        comparingVariable = ActiveCell    'SET VARIABLE EQUAL TO ACTIVE CELL

        Sheets("Sheet2").Select

        On Error Resume Next              'IN CASE YOU DON'T FIND WHAT YOU'RE LOOKING FOR

        Cells.Find(What:=comparingVariable, After:=ActiveCell, LookIn:=xlFormulas, LookAt _
        :=xlPart, SearchOrder:=xlByRows, SearchDirection:=xlNext, MatchCase:= _
        False, SearchFormat:=False).Activate                                        'PUT VARIABLE INTO FIND FUNCTION

        If Err.Number <> 0 Then                                                     'IF THERE WAS AN ERROR (WASN'T FOUND) HILIGHT CELL RED IN SHEET 1

            Sheets("Sheet1").Select
            ActiveCell.Interior.ColorIndex = 3

        End If


        i = i + 1               'ADDING TO ITERATOR

    Loop Until ActiveCell = ""

    Sheets("Sheet1").Select

End Sub
```

Add this data to an excel document and then use the code I posted above in an excel macro:

---

Sheet 1:
1
2
3
4
450
6
7
8
9
10
11
12
13
14
15
16
17
18
19
20
21
22
23
24
25

Sheet2:
25
24
23
22
21
20
19
18
17
16
15
14
13
12
11
10
9
8
7
6
5
4
3
2
1

---

-Sheet 1 has 1 - 25 listed in ascending order and sheet 2 has 1 - 25 in descending order except that I added a 450 in there to check if it catches something it can't find.

-According to the code if the number on sheet1 is not found in sheet2, that number will be hilighted red (thought I should clarify).

Hope this helps!

Comment: thanks Mike! While I choose nto to go with this code you did push me down the current path I'm on, as there are some thigns i'm going to do outside of the find fuction. but this is what i'm working on now.

Comment: sure thing, if you have any questions concerning what other methods you could use, just ask.